# How to deal with packages which install something into Assets folder?

Tags: unity-game-engine, github

Installing certain Unity packages will add something into Assets folder.

Three examples of packages:

1. `ProBuilder` will create a small

   Assets\ProBuilder Data\Default Material Palette.asset
2. `TextMesh Pro` will install 7 Mb (documentation, examples and actual assets) inside

   Assets\TextMesh Pro
3. The `Visual Effect Graph` goes even further by installing 27 Mb into

   Assets\Samples\Visual Effect Graph\12.1.6\VisualEffectGraph Additions

### Problem:

Assets folder is source controlled (I am using [this .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore)) and I was assuming that everything there is important. But above packages just add megabytes of their data (for a reason?) into it. And I don't know what should I do about it.

Custom Palette for ProBuilder is good to have, so I'd keep it. But what about others?? To example, in case of TextMesh Pro, I am not checking which fonts I am using and there are they located, maybe inside Assets, maybe somewhere else.

### My questions:

1. Should I just let those megabytes go into GitHub?
2. Should I add another .gitignore into Assets folder and carefully control what from which new package I want to upload with source and what not?
3. Perhaps some better solution exists?
4. Is it normal what packages doing it "their own way" or Unity is still not yet finished settling its rules for even official stuff?

I am thinking that packages should only be references and **not** source controlled. I saw many resources are used from deep within Packages folder (which is not source controlled). And this is fine - I just need to install package and all dependencies on such resources will be resolved. But Assets is going to be double-resolved, which doesn't makes sense to me.